# GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync on ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Trying to use this code on ASP.NET Core 2.0

```
ApplicationUser MyUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

var Code = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(MyUser, model.MobileNumber);
```

Results for variable "Code" is this instead of 6 digits.

CfDJ8Kjv6NuVfg5GkZ9ZEJRMBG2BxkZ4fnbwTfkq5335ft3Lm0sCl7uaRXFce+uDMtXC8wgdoiocyXV4nGlBz25tkbZr4JvZ6/1gk6EenJKmkq2of3XXfK/xMWE/M2aqmkz9OJpOe75Wz+xlmgq/HKZWtEgw17iQOULD3znVLtvr4t9Dche7u6N2YfrnP3hGxjwZJAaxmQksYc8ffO1m6xZNFCfZhfJsqG8JV+BgNp+5Bzk91d8PijFSyNADsXjq6G+w+g==

It works on ASP.NET Core 1.1.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

This is a confirmed bug, hopefully we'll see a patch **very soon** for this...

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1388

**EDIT** 2017-09-21

As a workaround, add the following configuration in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    //other stuff
    o.Tokens.ChangePhoneNumberTokenProvider = "Phone";
});
```

**EDIT** 2018-01-07

As of [.NET Core 2.0.3](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases/tag/v2.0.3), this has been patched and the workaround is no longer necessary.